# style select menu without javascript

Tags: css, xhtml

I know that this question has been asked over and over. I have read so many articles on the subject and it seems to me that the only cross browser solution comes with the use of jquery.

Unfortunately I am using dynamically dependent select menus. (I mean when you choose something from one, the other one changes its values). This is accomplished with a jquery script and everytime I try to style my select menus with jquery the dynamic dependency of menus broke.

So I decided to style them with the use of a background image and the most satisfactory solution was found from the answer of an another SO question.

http://jsfiddle.net/JeaffreyGilbert/PbYFT/

But still this solution doesnt work in Opera as the background image is shown behind the selected menu.

I know that many of you will tell me that one shouldnt style select menus. But still creating a very elegant site with some classy background and have those awful gray selected menus is a pain in the heart.

So is there a cross browser solution WITHOUT JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can style select menus to a point with out the use of javascript, but as far as 
I'm aware, if you're doing extra behaviors or you want a custom arrow you MUST use js at this time.